# Trouble with Basic Python exercise involving lists and indexes

Tags: python, arrays, list, sum

working on CheckIO exercises but stuck here. I need to design a function that'll find the sum of the elements with even indexes (0th, 2nd, 4th...) then multiply this summed number and the final element of the array together. The input is an array, the output is a number. Oh, and for an empty array, the result has to be zero.

```
def checkio(array):
    sum = 0
    if len(array) == 0: 
        return 0
    else:
        for i in array:    
            if array.index(i) % 2 == 0: 
                sum = sum + i
        final = sum*(array[len(array)-1])
    return final
```

for instance, with the array `[-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]`, this function is returning `-1476` when it should be giving out `1968`.

Comment: `if len(array) == 0:` can be shortened to `if array:`, and you don't have to use an else if you return in the if

Comment: @TimCastelijns I don't think it's a good idea to say that to someone struggling with this kind of problem without an in depth explanation. Especially when it's `if not array` ;)

Comment: @ThinkChaos I don't think this requires an indepth explanation, it's basic python

Comment: `index` just finds the element in the array and return the first appearance of the element so with an array with **repeated** elements your function won't work, (84 is repeated on your array)

Comment: Is the *last* element included in the sum?

Comment: @ThinkChaos I only just now noticed that `if array:` was wrong, perhaps I should have just shut my mouth indeed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working program I made.

```
def checkio(array):
    listSum = 0

    if array:

        for i in range(0, len(array), 2):
            listSum += array[i]

        finalValue = listSum * array[-1]

        return finalValue
    else:
        return 0
```

First, it checks to see if the array has any values. We can do that like this: `if array:`. If the array is empty, it will return 0 like you wanted.

Now, this is what checks every other element in your array: `range(0, len(array), 2):` This means that the value of `i` will start at 0, continue for the length of the array, and count by twos.

The sums are added here: `listSum += array[i]`. This takes the variable `listSum` and adds the value of the number at the index `i` in the array to it. the `+=` operator is shorthand for `listSum = listSum + array[i]`.

The last part of the function, takes the `listSum` variable, and multiplies it by `array[-1]` which gets the last value in the array and finnaly returns it.

When I ran your example array above, it returned 1968 as it should.

Comment: Thank you, please accept it if you found it the most helpful and concise.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see the issue is that you are assuming all numbers in the array are unique. For example lets say I have the following array:

```
[0,33,33,22,22]
```

obviously in this array you need the 3nd and 5th elements (index 2 and 4).

with your current code however this will never happen and you will end up with a sum of 0. This is because the code:

```
array.index(i)
```

finds the first element that matches `i`, this would be the 2nd and 4th elements (index 1 and 3), which are odd indexes, and thus will not be added.

Comment: Note: in OP's array, the 84 appears twice, the rest are unique

Comment: wait, we need the 1st and 3rd elements because we want the elements with even indexes ([0], [2]) ... wouldn't this explanation make more sense if the example array was something like [10, 11, 11, 12]? Then 11 wouldn't be added to the sum because the first index call would always return [1], not [2], and 1 is not an even number.

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce Fixed, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

You can use List [Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). Like:

```
sum([i for i in L[::2]])*L[-1]
```

In your code `array.index(i)` is problem . So you can use for finding elements by using `array[::2]`

You can try with your code:

```
def checkio(array):
    sum = 0
    if len(array) == 0: 
        return 0
    else:
        for i in array[::2]:    
            sum = sum + i
        final = sum*array[-1]
    return final
```

Example:

```
L = [-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]

Output:    
1968
```

Comment: Or `sum([i for i in L[:-1:2]])*L[-1]` if the last element is not supported to be part of the sum.

Comment: That's great, but OP is also interested in why his own code isnt working

Comment: what does :: mean in list comprehension?

Comment: @Spicy - I give a link in my answer #comprehension

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce Is's not a list comprehension, it's a slice. A slice is basically `[start:end:step]`. All of these can be left out.

Comment: Still don't answer why the OP code isn't working, the key issue is the misuse of `index`

Comment: when you use [start:end:2] it's mean you slice(take) your array element in after every 2 elements

Comment: thanks guys. i assume it starts at 0 by default? and the end number isn't inclusive, but ends at the number/entry right before it?

Comment: @Spicy- Hmm it starts at 0 and end with last if you use [ : : step]. also you slicing in array in any iteam number index like [ 3: 8 : step=2] its mean you start in index 3 and end with index 7 ie. 3 5 7 index you visited

Answer (score 1):

I think it is in order to to some beginner's explanation even if I'm repeating what other answers already said:

As for why your code does not work, let's change the original a little:

```
def checkio(array):
    sum = 0
    if len(array) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in array:
            print "pos of %s = %i" % (i, array.index(i))
            if array.index(i) % 2 == 0:
                sum = sum + i
            final = sum*(array[len(array)-1])
    return final
```

This yields

```
pos of -37 = 0
pos of -36 = 1
pos of -19 = 2
pos of -99 = 3
[...]
pos of 84 = 9
[...]
pos of 84 = 9
```

There's your problem, because `index()` yields the index of the first occurrence of an element and `84` appears twice. Your code only works when the elements in the array are unique, which they are not.

So, when not going for the all out python swagger using slicing:

```
def checkio(array):
    # sum is a built-in, don't override it
    result = 0
    # "if len(array) != 0" is the same as "if array"
    if array:
        # enumerate is nice, but not really needed, see below
        for i, x in enumerate(array):    
            # i is the index, x is the value
            if i % 2 == 0: 
                # += is also nice
                result += x
        result *= array[-1]
    return result
```

As for a more pythonic solution, you can do a lot with [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html).

```
array[::2]
```

is *every second element of `array`* and

```
array[-1]
```

is the last element. Hence

```
s = sum(array[::2]) * array[-1]
```

That does not handle an empty array, thus

```
# if there are no elements or only the last element, the sum is zero
if len(array) == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return sum(array[::2]) * array[-1]
```

or even

```
return sum(array[::2]) * array[-1] if array else 0
```

Which is python's equivalent of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just use enumerate to interate for each element with an index and keep track of the last element.

```
def checkio(array):
    sum = 0
    last_element = 0

    for index, element in enumerate(array):
        if index % 2 == 0:
           sum += element
        last_element = element

    return last_element * sum
```